# How to use different databases bewteen local and cloud execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, azure, configuration

I have an ASP.NET MVC4 solution that i deploy on Azure. This solution connects to a SQL database.

I would like to know if the solution can be configured so that, when i run it on my local machine (i.e. while developping/debuging) it uses a **local** database, and when it's run in the cloud (i.e. on Azure) it uses **the cloud database**.

I know this sort of configuration is possible for the Storage Account (blob, queue) connection strings, but so far I haven't been able to find any equivalent for the databases connection string.

Thanks to anyone who is willing to help me with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to configure your web.config file to set up the right connection string. For a local database you just need something like this :

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=mydb;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\mydbmdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Then add a web.Release.config file where you will use the transformation statement to change the connection string, like that.

```
 <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=xxx.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=xxx;User Id=xxx@xxx;Password=xxx;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" xdt:Transform="Replace"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PaaS Cloud Services, you can specify separate cscfg files (local, dev, prod). When you run locally via the emulators, you'll use the "local" version. Then when you deploy to the cloud, you can use a different version.

If we're talking Web Sites, or IaaS, the most common approach I've seen used is to have a way to detect which environment (local or hosted) you're running in. Normally based on either a machine name (less common) or the request URI (fairly common). Then in your code you use the appropriate connection string configuration setting for the environment you are running in.

Comment: thanks for your help. *.cscfg files are what we use to provide different settings related to the Storage Account but I couldn't find a way to use them to soolve my problem. @Whirly 's solution (transform attribute in web.Release.config / web.Debug.config) works like a charm